# Как отправлять события с параметрами в Яндекс.Метрику?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-метрика

В [Аппметрике](https://appmetrica.yandex.ru/) можно отправлять события с параметрами. Потом можно развернуть событие и посмотреть статистику по каждому параметру.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как такое же делать в Яндекс.Метрике? Я использую метод reachGoal, предварительно создав конверсию *Open ticket*. Во вкладке конверсии вижу событие, но как посмотреть статистику по параметрам?

```
yaCounter.reachGoal('Open ticket', {number: 1});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел. Отчет называется - "**Параметры визитов**".
Но интерфейс запутан по сравнению с аппметрикой. Не очень удобно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]